# How can I get the users subscribed to a plan?

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

I need a query or scope that can retrieve all the users subscribed to a named plan by Laravel Cashier.

Answer (score 0):

I added this scope to the User model:

```
use Laravel\Cashier\Subscription;
.
.
.
public function scopePremiumUsers($query)
{
    return $query->whereHas('subscriptions', function($query) {
        $query->where('stripe_plan', 'USERPLANNAME')
            ->where(function($q){
                $q->where('stripe_status', 'trialing')
                    ->orWhere('stripe_status', 'active');
            });
    });
}
```